# Return value of glSelectBuffer in opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl

```
static GLuint selectBuff[BUFFER_LENGTH];
glSelectBuffer(BUFFER_LENGTH, selectBuff);
..
//Draw something..
..
// Collect the hits
hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
..
..
if(hits > 0){ //something's been selected
        fprintf(stderr,"something has been selected");
        unsigned int choiche;

        // fi there's more than one figure (or control point) selected, take the top one
        if (hits > 1)
              choiche = selectBuff[(hits*4)-1]; 
        else
              choiche = selectBuff[3];
        cpsel = false;
```

I basically want to know the structure of selectBuff. What does the author meaning by coding `selectBuff[3]` and `selectBuff[(hits*4)-1]`?

Official doc says, buffer returns values from the name stack. But, that doesn't actually tell me what author meant by doing `selectBuff[3]`.

For complete code (it's a paint program) [see here](http://sprunge.us/Wbif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glSelectBuffer.xml

> "The hit record consists of the number
>   of names in the name stack at the time
>   of the event, followed by the minimum
>   and maximum depth values of all
>   vertices that hit since the previous
>   event, followed by the name stack
>   contents, bottom name first."

Therefore, it should be the name stack contents.

Comment: Wouldn't the max depth value be selectBuff[2]?

Comment: It must be Monday.  Yes - editing answer - thanks for the catch.